# why this code shows an empty array list even though i added elements to it during request?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-volley

my code is like this, i don't know why it's getting an empty array even though i added the elements to the array during request.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
 private List<Question> questionList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    questionList = new QuestionBank().getQuestions();
            Log.d("Main",  "processFinished: " + questionList);


}
```

// the request 
    public class QuestionBank {

```
ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private String url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curiousily/simple-quiz/master/script/statements-data.json";


public List<Question> getQuestions() {
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            Question question = new Question();
                            question.setAnswer(response.getJSONArray(i).get(0).toString());
                            question.setAnswerTrue(response.getJSONArray(i).getBoolean(1));


                            questionArrayList.add(question);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
    return questionArrayList;
}
}
```

// Log result

```
D/Main: processFinished: []
```

Comment: are you sure your JsonArrayRequest add item into the array? Try to debug on it

Comment: Add a log statement inside the onResponse when you add to the list and you'll see the issue

Comment: add a callback interface and pass and call it from  onResponse(JSONArray response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback as following ways

**step 1:**

Create an Intercafe

```
public interface TestCallBack {
        void callBack(List<Question> response) ;
}
```

**Step 2:**
create anonymous objects

```
TestCallBack testCallBack=new TestCallBack() {

            @Override
            public void callBack(List<Question> response) {
                // here you will get a response after success
            }
        };
```

and pass this reference to

```
 questionList = new QuestionBank().getQuestions(testCallBack);
            Log.d("Main",  "processFinished: " + questionList);
```

**Step 3:**

call this method from after the response from the server

```
public List<Question> getQuestions(TestCallBack testCallBack) { 

 public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

 testCallBack.callBack(questionArrayList); // pass your array list here
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is empty because you are populating it ***asynchronously***. you should add a callback as a parameter, call it in `onResponse`.

Comment: Perhaps you can expand on this answer with how that would be done?